# How to save and read a matrix by constructing dictionary from csv using python?

Tags: python

I have an image I(400 X 400). I constructed a dictionary 
{'my_Im': I} and save it using csv.
When open the *csv, I can see a cell is 'my_Im', but the second cell in the same line is like '0 0 0 ...0 0 0'.

When I try to open the csv file, I found that I lost all the values in '...'.

What is the correct way to save my image into a dictionary without losing elements using python?

Comment: What was `A` that you wrote to the file?

Comment: I have edit my question

Comment: I just found that the “...” in the results are string "..."! Does it mean that the way I save my dictionary was wrong?

Comment: The dictionary is alright and contains all the data but you messed up saving this. I don't quite see how this should be represented in a CSV file anyway. Can you explain what you _expect_ to see in that file?  Where does the key go?  And where the value which is actually a 2D structure of values. How should this be saved in _one_ cell?

Comment: probably best not idea to use a dict to store it, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Actually, I have many parameters and results for analysing one image. I want to save them all in one file which I can easily check (like excels, which dose not need code to read the data). I thought csv was good. But then I found the problem for saving big images matrix.

Comment: Exactly, the dictionary was ok. But data were lost while saving as CSV. Why is that? Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: Describe the data you have and how the result should look like. As you say there is more in that dictionary and you don't tell how exactly you expect the CSV file to look like. Which information should go where? Why exactly the data is lost is guesswork unless you tell what exactly you have coded to save the data. The array representation with the ellipsis (…) is something you get when converting the array to a string, to prevent the user to be overwhelmed by too many numbers he can't make sense of anyway by just looking at them without tools.